# getting SyntaxError in range

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to load a file in Python3 but getting following syntax error:

```
def load_file():
    phone_dict.clear()
    while True:
        try:
            fname = input('Enter file to load: ')
            in_file = open(fname, 'r')
            a_list = in_file.readlines()
            for i range(0, len(a_list), 2):
                key_str = (a_list[i].strip('\n'))
                val_str = (a_list[i + 1].strip('\n'))
                phone_dict[key_str] = val_str
            print(fname, 'sucessfully loaded.')
            in_file.close()
            break
        except FileNotFoundError:
            print('File not found. Re-enter.')
```

Error:

```
for i range(0, len(a_list), 2):
          ^
```

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Appreciate any help for resolving this error.

Comment: I think i was missing ... in there.  for i in range

Comment: yep, no problem. Thanks for putting effort in the question and putting code examples, but we will close this question soon because it cannot help anyone else since its irreproducible typo :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need:

```
for i in range(etc):
```

Comment: Don't waste time posting an answer to a trivial typo error. Just VTC as typo.

Comment: I guess we each choose how we want to interact.

Comment: @Barmar Good point because this wouldn't help or be searchable through a google search, so I also voted to close

Comment: Yeah, it would be a shame if we just helped the person asking the question.

Answer (score 1):

It's resolved.  I was missing an `in` with the `for` loop :)

```
for i in range(0, len(a_list), 2):
```